# Can someone tell me why is the title look like this?

Tags: titles, titlesec, titletoc, frame-title, section-titles

[image]

```
\makeatother%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\Alph{subsection}}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}                                                                 %
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Roman{table}}        
\usepackage{blindtext}   %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{Análise estática do conversor Boost acoplado}
\author{Tomás Adão Gonçalves\\ PPGEE, DELC,CT, UFSM-Universidade Federal de Santa Maria\\e-mail:tomasadaogo@gmail.com }
\date{August 2020}

\begin{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Please post a small complete code, reproducing the problem, that we can test.

Comment: My guess is you need to add `\raggedright` to the chapter/section title, either by default or on an as-needed basis.  To me, it appears as if the title is being justified to the margins.

Comment: none of the lines of code that you show are related to the text in in the image